# Where is the recommended place to use $http.get

Tags: angularjs

I am playing around with angularjs and have the following HTML:-

```
   <div ng-app="App">
      <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
         <products></products>
      </div>
   </div>
```

and my js looks like this:-

```
var app = angular.module('App', []);

app.controller("AppCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
   $http.get('/api/products')
      .then(function(res) {
         $scope.products = res.data;
   });
});

app.directive("products", function () {
   return {
      restrict: "E",
      template: "<h1>Products</h1><ul><li ng-repeat='product in products'>{{product.Name}} - <em>{{product.Category}}</em></li></ul>",
   };
});
```

This works really well but I am unsure how the directive knows that the controller has loaded the data before the template renders the results. So my question is:-

Is the recommended way to use a `$http.get` in this scenario (explanation would be nice) or if not then what is the recommended way?

Comment: So, this is working fine, but you want to know why / how it works?

Comment: yes and no! if this is recommended way then I can assume the framework just does some magic and if not then what is recommend way.

Comment: I think you're worrying about the wrong thing. You should use $http.get when you need data, and not worry about the template (if it works). If the template doesn't work, you should then look into how angularjs uses $apply() to propagate changes in your model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a fine use of `$http.get`. At the end of the day, it's just a tool for doing ajax requests.

It seems your question stems from a fear that your directive will mysteriously break in different scenarios, which is understandable. The key, then, is to understand that data binding is Angular's secret weapon.

One way to think about it, Angular compiles everything and throws it into an event / digest loop. So, it is able to detect dependencies, watch for changes to variables, and call dependent methods (such as your products directive) when those variables change.

The Angular guide does a great job of providing conceptual diagrams for further understanding, and it's here: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts

Comment: Great explanation I suppose I am used to a world where I have a callback function AFTER the data has successfully been retrieved. The fact that it can detect and wire up `$http.get` dependencies never occurred to me.